# How to find this determinant value

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Consider the matrix:

$L=$\begin{bmatrix}
x-5 && k && k && k&& k&& k\\k && x-5 && k && k&& k&& k\\k && k && x-5 && k&& k&& k\\k && k && k && x-4&& 0&& k\\k && k && k && 0&& x-3&& 0\\k && k && k && k&& 0&& x-4
\end{bmatrix}

The problem is I want to find the determinant of $L$ in terms of determinant of $L_{1,2,3}$ where $L_{1,2,3}$  is the matrix obtained by deleting the rows and columns corresponding to ${1,2,3}$.

Here $k\in \Bbb R$.

If $k=1$ then the solution is easy $\det L$ can be obtained by first multiplying the first row by $x-1$ and then applying the elementary row operations etc.

But I am having problem for $k\neq 1$

if $k\neq 1$ then $R_1=R_1(x-1)-R_2-R_3-\dots -R_n$

gives $R_1=$
$(x^2-6x+5(1-k), (k-1)(x-5),\dots ,(k-1)(x-5))$

and hence can't be expanded in terms of $L_{1}$ as in case of $k=1$.

Please give some hints on how to proceed in this case.

Comment: What does "deleting the rows and columns of 1,2,3"  mean?  Do you mean to delete **all** the first three rows and three columns and remain with a $\;3\times3\;$ determinant? How?!